# Jsoup - Get Parent

Tags: java, android, html, maven, jsoup

I have some HTML and I am trying to get a link, and I know a few qualities the link I want will have so I can find it easily, but not I also want to get the `<h2 calss='locs'>` tag above the link I have. So the html might  look like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2 class = 'locs'>text</h2>
        <p>
           <a link and stuff...>
        </p>
        <h2 class = 'locs'>foo</h2>
        <p>
           <a another link and stuff...>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the `<h2>` isn't always just the first parent of the `<a>` so is there a way to search for the  that comes before the link?

Thanks for the help

Comment: @speng10 I cannot understand your Question. Can you rewrite your Question? The English is garbled. Perhaps break it up into short sentences. Be specific in the details and example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure what you are asking, but this is what I assume: You want the first `a` Element after a `h2` Element of class `locs`.

To do this, you can#t use the `parent()` method, since the `a` elements parents seem to be `p` elements which are in turn siblings (not children) of the `h2.locs` Elements. Here is what i would do:

```
Elements as = doc.select("h2.locs + p>a");
```

Explanation:

- `h2.locs` looks for h2 elments with class locs
- `A + B` looks for B which must be direct sibling to the previous A.
- `p>a` looks for `a` elements which are children of `p`